# Image slightly distorted in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView, inside that are UIImageViews all 198*198pts. The images in this scrollview all seem to be slightly distorted. The edges are more jagged (I am working with png files and the images are cartoons/stickers). In a normal UIImageView not contained in a UIScrollView they look fine. Could anyone give me some pointers to why this might be happening?

```
UIView *content = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.stickers count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    for(int i=0; i<[self.stickers count]; i++){

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        MySticker *sticker = self.stickers[i];
        imageView.image=sticker.image;
        imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [content addSubview:imageView];
        //NSLog(@"scroll view width is %f",self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
        //NSLog(@"ImageView width is %f", imageView.frame.size.width);
    }



    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(content.frame.size.width ,content.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:content];
```

EDIT ^ added my scrollview setup above

Comment: is the size of the imageview the same as the size of the actual image?

Comment: do you correctly assign a contentMode?

Comment: The actual image is 600*600 pixels. The setup for the UIImageView outside the scrollview and inside the scrollview seems to be the same. But the image inside the scrollview is noticeably distorted.

Comment: @heximal I tired imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; and imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; didn't make a difference.